# How to parse a string containing a backslash in R?

Tags: r

I'm wondering if it is possible to `parse` a string with a backslash without causing an error. E.g.,

```r
c('\\') # valid r code
#> [1] "\\"
parse(text = "c('\\')")
#> Error in parse(text = "c('\\')"): <text>:1:3: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
#> 1: c('\')
#>       ^
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Your text is different from your first line of code.  To get that line of code, you would enter text `"c('\\\\')"`, because within a string constant, the backslash is an escape character.